# Complex type as optional argument in web api action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, optional-arguments

I need to make a complex type parameter optional in 'Web API controller action', so that my action filter for null values can ignore it by checking the argument's property `IsOptional`. I'm getting this error:

> Optional parameter 'errorCode' is not supported by 'FormatterParameterBinding'.

I have a controller like this:

```
[Route("api/v1/Temp/{number}/{errorCode?}/{value?}")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult Temp(int number, ErrorDetail errorCode = null, string value = null)
{
    return Ok("good");
}
```

and have actionFilter to check null values like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    var parameters = actionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters();
    foreach (var param in parameters)
    {
        if (param.IsOptional)
            continue;

        object value = null;

        if (actionContext.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(param.ParameterName))
            value = actionContext.ActionArguments[param.ParameterName];

        if (value == null)
            throw new GasException((ulong)ErrorCodes.NullValue, ErrorCodes.NullValue.GetDescription());
    }
}
```

Is there any way to make complex-types optional parameter?
How to ignore complex-type optional parameters in action-filter?

Comment: I have found a way around, by using custom attribute on my controller action, which takes all the optional parameters and then skip those optional parameters in NULL value filter.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you can.  If the client making the request does not provide a value for the complex type parameter then it will automatically be provided as `null` by ASP.NET Web API since they are reference types.

Hence, no need to explicitly set them with a default value of `null`:

```
public IHttpActionResult Temp(int number, ErrorDetail errorCode, string value)
{
    return Ok("good");
}
```

By removing the `= null` default values in the method signature above that error regarding "optional param not supported..." goes away.

Not sure the intent of your action filter since you're checking for `null`s and throwing an exception. That implies those parameters are truly *required* not optional.